AWS - Storing IAM logs in bucket
I have been trying to store IAM logs only in my s3 bucket. I initiated cloudtrail to store management logs in my s3 bucket.
I tried a lambda function that that filters out IAM logs but this code will only filter the logs that are already stored in my s3 bucket. I want to store filtered logs only to the bucket
Tho I found this filter to filter out logs in cloudwatch
fields @timestamp, eventName, eventSource, userIdentity.userName
| filter eventSource = "iam.amazonaws.com"
| filter eventName like /^(Add|Attach|Change|Create|Deactivate|Delete|Detach|Enable|Put|Remove|Set|Update|Upload)/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20

also I tried to apply policy to cloudtrail through json file of same function as below
{
    "advancedEventSelectors": [
      {
        "eventSource": [
          "iam.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "eventName": [
          "Add*",
          "Attach*",
          "Change*",
          "Create*",
          "Deactivate*",
          "Delete*",
          "Detach*",
          "Enable*",
          "Put*",
          "Remove*",
          "Set*",
          "Update*",
          "Upload*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  

but I didn't find a room to insert this json policy
i even tried
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name MyNewTrail --advanced-event-selectors file:\\C:\Users\Public\Desktop\p5.json    

command but that too got me this error
Error parsing parameter '--advanced-event-selectors': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)                         JSON received: {      

